# Android Runtime Error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils "

Tags: android

I am trying to use org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils in Android. The sample is below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CheckCommonsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String email1 = "xyz@gmail.com";
    String email2 = "abc@gmail.com";
    String email3 = "mnp@gmail.com";
    String email4 = null;       

    ArrayList<String> emailList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    emailList1.add(email4);
    emailList1.add(email1);
    emailList1.add(email2);
    emailList1.add(email3);

    ArrayList<String> emailList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    emailList2.add(email3);
    emailList2.add(email2);
    emailList2.add(email1);

    boolean isEqual = CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(emailList1,
 emailList2);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText(String.valueOf(isEqual));
   }
 }
```

I have imported commons-collections-3.2.1.jar to Build Path of Android Project, but I am getting error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils` at runtime.

**Edit1**

[image: Android Project Artifact]

Thanks

Comment: @st0le Cleaning project does not help.

Comment: What is there in Android Dependencies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put the library in /libs (not /lib) folder of your android project

Edit: I was assuming that you put it in /lib folder because this is a common failure. In your added screenshot can be seen that you included the lib as external jar. Anyway..whether you put it in /lib or as external jar the solution is the same: create /libs folder and put the lib there

Comment: Appended a image showing the android project. I could not find the /libs or /lib folder.

Comment: You have to create the /libs folder in your android project. Put your lib in there. In Eclipse select build path and "Add Jars..." (not "External Jars")