# Dalvik VM gives error while using org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils

Tags: android

I am trying to use org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils in android with following code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CheckCommonsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String email1 = "xyz@gmail.com";
    String email2 = "abc@gmail.com";
    String email3 = "mnp@gmail.com";
    String email4 = null;       

    ArrayList<String> emailList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    emailList1.add(email4);
    emailList1.add(email1);
    emailList1.add(email2);
    emailList1.add(email3);

    ArrayList<String> emailList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    emailList2.add(email3);
    emailList2.add(email2);
    emailList2.add(email1);

    boolean isEqual = CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(emailList1,
           emailList2);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText(String.valueOf(isEqual));
    }
 }
```

I am getting following error message in Console 
**Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1**. Complete Message trail is uploaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?mumsijp7kbauidm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is okay. It seems like a jar files conflict. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389640/924149). Can have several reasons why that error raises..one of the solutons there may help you too

Edit: Assuming from your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089989/android-runtime-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-collec): You added the lib from /libs folder as I descibed there but you forgot to delete the "old" reference to your external library in build path. So you probably include the same library twice. Remove the reference of your external jar from build path

Comment: There was some problem with the project, I copied the code to another project and it worked fine. Thanks.